# Can't insert into SQL Server database using node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ssms

I am using Node.js as my bcknd and trying to send some dummy numbers into a SQL Server database. It was literally working fine, but `INSERT` suddenly stopped working..  Does anyone have any ideas on this? Not working, I meant not inserting the row.

**node.js**

```
//connect and send to SQL Server database
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
  server: '',
  database: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  port: 1433
};

app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.body);
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  console.log(jsondata);
}
)

function insertRow() {
  var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);
  dbConn.connect().then(function () {
    var transaction = new sql.Transaction(dbConn);
    transaction.begin().then(function () {
      var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
      request.query("Insert into test (schoool, name, location) values (3,1,1)").then(function (recordset) {
        console.log('Affected:' + request.rowsAffected);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('SQL Connetion Error: ' + err);
      }
    })
  })
}

insertRow();
```

I am getting this message on the SQL Server side, but I'm not sure if this causes the problem:

> Lock request time out period exceeded

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please choose the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Don't see you closing connections or committing transactions. You might have open transactions that are locking the table. Dispose of you connections properly and this might correct your issue.